# How to create an empty folder on build in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a VS2010 project which needs to create a *dataIn* and a *dataOut* directory in the *bin\debug* directory to allow some tests to run.

Creating the *dataIn* directory is easy - just add the folder with the contents to the project and set the "Copy To Output Directory" property for each of the files it contains to "Copy always" (or edit the project file to use a wildcard to catch all files, as suggested by other answers on SO) - the directory will be created automatically by VS so that the files can be copied into it.

**My question:** how can I ensure the *dataOut* directory is created automatically when needed?

There are no files to go in it, so there is nothing for this directory in the ItemGroup. If I add an entry for the directory to the project file by hand then I get the error:

```
"<path>\dataOut" is actually a directory.  The "Copy" task does not support copying directories.
```

(edit: removed underscores from the directory names so the italics would work!)

Answer (score 16):

Try this in the pre-build step:

```
if not exist "$(TargetDir)dataOut" mkdir "$(TargetDir)dataOut"
```

The quotes are important if you have spaces somewhere in `$(TargetDir)`, but I'd use them regardless for robustness.

Answer (score 7):

One way I've managed so far is the rather obvious step of adding a dummy text file to the folder and setting its "Copy to Output Directory" property to "Copy always". I've also added a post-build step to remove the dummy file afterwards, leaving the now-empty directory behind (although for this particular project, that's really only due to my fussiness - there'd be no impact if it wasn't there).

I'd still like to know if there's a better option, though ...

Answer (score 0):

how about some mkdirs in the prebuild step?

Comment: I think EvilTeach is actually providing an answer (try creating the directory explicitly in a pre-build/post-build step using MKDIR), although in a rhetorical question form. The reason I've avoided that is it becomes more complicated because you also have to test for the existence of the directory first, etc. I'd ideally like to avoid having to remember there are pre/post-build steps in the project at all if possible, because they're not as obvious as having a folder in the solution explorer (although I do have the post-build step to tidy up the dummy file in my current solution)

Comment: I use to post build to copy api headers to a common include directory.

Answer (score 0):

Having just shared this dilemma, it occurs to me that the easiest way to handle this would be to simple create the directory programmatically.

```c#
if(!Directory.Exists(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "yourDirectoryName"))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "yourDirectoryName");
}
```

I'm not sure what type of application you are working with, but winform apps can do this in their Main method, and web apps could do this in a number of places.

Comment: The dataOut directory is only need to run some tests in the development environment. Adding explicit code to create it on customer systems which will never need it is not the way to go!